# How to set PowerShell 7 as default and remove other versions

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to set `PowerShell 7` as the *default shell*. So when I shift right click in File Explorer and click on `"Open PowerShell window here"`  in the context menu, I want `PowerShell 7` to come up.

And I want to remove completely the other versions.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: [1] you CANNOT remove ps5.1 - it is required by several things in windows. [*grin*] ///// [2] the installer for ps7+ has an option to add it to the context menu. have you tried re-running the installer?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey [1] my ps5.1 is broken and I want to replace it totally by ps7, [2] I added ps7 it to the context menu

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue. Which is why we are here. SO has rules we are told we are to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can set PowerShellv7 (PWSH.exe) as your default. You cannot uninstall the versions that ship with the OS (Windows PowerShell -- powershell.exe and powershell_ise.exe); that is by design;, nor would you want to as PSv7 is not 100% on par with Win PS, and will call those cmdlets, for the ones it does not have. Mkaing changes to the registry for context menu stuff,  set the file associate of all .ps* to pwsh.exe, put the pwsh.exe icon as a shorcut on your desktop and only use that.

Comment: @postanote thanks for your note, I updated the tags, removed `powershell` one.

Comment: @postanote *"You can set PowerShellv7 (PWSH.exe) as your default."* how can I do that please?

Comment: On install PS7 on right-click is an option. Without messing with the registry, you can set pin the pwsh shortcuts to your desktop, set pwsh in default applications or in Explorer, right-click *.ps* file (not recommended -  *.ps* is set to a text editor for a reason);  pin it to the Start Menu, and remote the PowerShell shortcuts from your desktop, and the Start Menu, VSCode, to always use push in the user settings, same thing the Windows Terminal. As for Open here, WinX Menu, and right-click in explorer, you have to modify the registry. There are web articles showing how to do the reg hack.

Comment: @Bilal - good to know you got the ps7+ stuff working. [*grin*] ///// take a look at `dsim.exe` and `sfc.exe` for ways to _possibly_ fix your ps5.1 setup.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**To make PowerShell 7 the default shell for Windows Terminal, follow these steps:**

1. Click on the down arrow and press **settings**
2. A json file will open, and you will see a line near the top that has a parameter called defaultProfile with a UUID. (You may have to click the ***'Open JSON file'*** button first, on the settings UI that opens)
3. Also you will see a line representing the UUID of the PowerShell 7.0
4. Copy that UUID and put it in for defaultProfile

Good Luck!

Source:

> https://www.codyhosterman.com/2020/05/defaulting-windows-terminal-to-powershell-7-x-core/

[image: The Down Arrow Menu and Settings]

[image: Open JSON file button]

[image]

Comment: I don't see the option `down arrow` to press `settings`!.

Comment: You can try to access the file settings.json directly from here [update the path accordingly in your computer]: C:\users\$env:UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_*\LocalState\settings.json

Comment: I don't have this file, I maybe delete it by mistake before, so I don't have functional core PS.

Comment: If you want to simplify it - You can also try to use Win X editor - just to put powershell 7 as default in your editor:  https://winaero.com/winx-menu-editor-v3-0/

Comment: Last option is to edit these registry keys to access powershell7 (through regedit in run): [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere]
@="&PowerShell here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere\command]
@="cmd.exe /c start \"PS\" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command \"cd \\\"%1\\\"\"

Comment: @Bilal, do you have [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/get-started#:~:text=%20Install%20and%20set%20up%20Windows%20Terminal%20,profile%20by%20pressing%20ctrlshiftt%20or%20by...%20More) and [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) installed? The dropdown arrow, `ALUFTW` is part of the Windows Terminal GUI, it can't be removed that I am aware of and should not even if one could. Since it is what allows access to all configured shells.

Comment: Now you can see all the profiles in Settings, click on the original "Powershell" profile and delete it (delete button is at the bottom).

Comment: Windows 11 now opens the SETTINGS dialog.  You can then change the default profile (above default terminal application) to "Powershell" from "Windows Powershell".

Comment: No Windows Powershell profile for me on Windows 11. I've installed latest powershell 7.0

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it mention terminal, yet this answer right away assumes the OP wants to remove from terminal. And this is the accepted answer! SO has become strange these days.

Comment: This is also outdated, as Windows Terminal can now be configured with a proper GUI. The option to edit the Json file is still there, but it's less convenient, and it must be selected intentionally, by clicking on "Open JSON file" in the lower-left corner. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: If **"Windows Terminal GUI"** is not installed then run "Microsoft Store" and install it after you search it. Then you have "Windows Terminal GUI" and you can manage more described  settings.

Comment: You need to shift-click on the settings option.

Answer (score 16):

If you have Windows Terminal: Follow these steps:
Click the dropdown and go to `Settings`

On the General Tab, you will see default profile, click the dropdown and select the profile you would like to be default
[image: Windows terminal screen to selext default profile]

Comment: ... "and I want to remove completely the other versions"

Comment: Anyway to fix the mouse right click context menu 'run as PowerShell"?

Comment: Powershell 7 does not show up even after installing it and rebooting (Windows 11)

Comment: Type in the search bar 'Powershell7' and it will show up. I have it pinned to my task bar.

Comment: Do you mean [this windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install) and / or [this github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)?

Answer (score 6):

As of 2023.3.30 - for windows 11

- Install PowerShell from [windows store](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9N0DX20HK701?rtc=1&hl=de-de&gl=DE).
- Open terminal
- click little dropdown arrow and choose settings
- change default to the new PowerShell logo (not Windows PowerShell)
- click save and then close and restart terminal

[image]

Comment: deadly hurt, it's true

Answer (score -2):

to change powerShell version in windows 11, follow these steps

1. Open powerShell and go to setting by clicking down arrow
2. in Profiles tab (left side in menu) choose Windows PowerShell
3. edit the Command Line to powerShell Directory Like C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe
4. Save settings

that's it